# bundler not working with rack application

Tags: ruby, bundler, rack

Here is my code

```
# config.ru
require "rubygems"
require "bundler"
Bundler.setup
Bundler.require

FooApp = Proc.new do |env|
  [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'}, "foo"]
end
Routes = Rack::Mount::RouteSet.new do |set|
  set.add_route FooApp, { :request_method => 'GET', :path_info => %r{^/foo$} }, {}, :foo
end
run Routes
```

My Gemfile looks like this

```
source :rubygems
gem 'rack-mount'
```

I did bundle install which produced Gemfile.lock.

When I run

```
rackup config.ru
```

I get following error

```
uninitialized constant Rack::Mount (NameError)
```

The code works if I remove dependency on bundler. However I want bundler to work . This code is a small form of large application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bundler.require` tries to load a file called `rack-mount.rb` (same as the name of the gem) inside the gem's `lib` directory. That's a Rubygems convention. With most Rack gem's this does not work, because they don't contain such a file.

Instead it's all about namespacing. rack-mount's `lib` folder for example contains a `rack` folder which contains a file called `mount.rb` (see [rack-mount/tree/master/lib](https://github.com/josh/rack-mount/tree/master/lib) on GitHub).

To fix the problem, you have to tell Bundler which file to require:

```
source :rubygems
gem "rack-mount", :require => "rack/mount"
```

The Bundler documentation contains further information about [how to write a Gemfile](http://gembundler.com/gemfile.html).